# Multiple users in git, coming from using mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial, merge

I'm using git for a class project so I can work with my team. I used mercurial last semester for this but have switched to git since msysgit has a portable version.

In mercurial, when 2 users made changes from the same changeset, one pushes, and the others commits would become a separate branch that they would have to merge into the master branch even though they had never explicitly made a separate branch (as in both were master branches with no other branches created, but the existence of different commits by the first user made the other user's commits look like another branch on the commit tree in bitbucket).

Would the same thing happen in git? Can multiple users work only on a master branch then merge in the new changes like in mercurial when they pull? Or do you have to make branches? Or am I just thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Can you explain "2 users made changes from the same changeset"?

Comment: Basically we both have the same changeset on or local machines. One adds done features and pushes, then the other adds done other features and and has to pull on merge. Neither however made a.new branch and were working on the master branch.

Comment: OK, I have cooked up an answer, I hope it is clear enough...

Answer (score 2):

Given what you explained, you have to operate the same way with git.

With mercurial as with git, your two devs started developing features from the same point M. Dev 1 creates M1 via his/her changes, dev 2 creates M2.

Basically, the first dev who pushes wins. If it is dev1, when dev2 tries and push M->M2, the push will fail because the remote's point is actually M1, not M.

Which means dev2 has two choices:

- either (s)he pulls from the remote, in which case a merge commit will be created, which will be pushable;
- or (s)he fetches, and rebases his/her changeset on top of M1, creates M2', and pushes.

In the first case, the sequence of commands is:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

(*please note that in a casual setup, origin and master are the default remote and branch by default, which means these arguments are optional... These commands are therefore probably overkill. But I don't like surprises :p*)

and the tree will be:

```
M---...---M1--C    # C is a merge commit
 \           /
  \---.....M2
```

In the second case, the sequence of commands is:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git push origin master
```

and the tree will be:

```
M ---...M1---...----M2'  # M2 rebased on top of M1
```

Now, which solution is chosen is really about politics. Some projects prefer solution 1, some others prefer solution 2. Git doesn't care about politics ;)

Comment: Yes, yes, I know these are the default values... At least for the first case. You do need to specify it for rebase though.

Comment: So in the first case a pull action automatically causes a merge? (and of course any conflicts would pull up kdiff, which I assume is built into msysgit) That's great it makes it take one less step to explain to my team than I had to for mercurial last semester.

Comment: @Portaljacker if there is a conflict, your diff program will be invoked in both cases. The difference is that with a rebase, the diff program will be invoked precisely at the moment where M1 and (to be) M2' will conflict. This makes it more localized, but please note that whenever a conflict occurs, after resolving the conflict you have to `git add` the files in conflict. I don't know how Mercurial handles that.

Comment: @Portaljacker as to whether kdiff is built into msysgit, I have no idea... I'm a command line user and am used to resolving conflicts using vim ;) (and with `merge.conflictStyle` set to `diff3`)

Comment: It seems like I'll have to add kdiff3. But it looks that when you pull it auto-merges, which is perfect. If that's correct then I'll tick this as the answer.